# Collaborative tool for code reviews that accommodates remote teams

Tags: code-review, github

Let's assume the following criteria:

- A team of developers work in different locations and timezones
- These developers often work on other projects and don't necessarily have the bandwidth to always do code reviews "live"
- Github is the version control tool of choice
- A web-based tool would be optimal, especially if it could integrate directly with Github.

This team of developers needs the ability to collaboratively comment on design suggestions in an ad-hoc way (including replies and suggestions).

Here's an example of one web-based tool I found, but the experience was very confusing and arduous:

[image]

Probably the closest technology I've seen that exhibits the behavior we're looking for is web-based document editors (like Google Docs) that allow inline comments and discussion.

Does such a thing exist? (And no, "blame" and forking in Github is not adequate!)

Answer (score 1):

I had a pretty good experience with Reviewboard https://www.reviewboard.org, I recommended it before: [Peer review software for programming assignments](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/20403)

Specifically for your requirements:

- works great for geographically dispersed teams
- review actions are very granular (comments/answers/issues/edits/etc) and can be executed independently or can be batched and published together at any time (no 'live review' behaviour)
- according to their page it supports hosting services including Github

Comment: I did see that in my travels, but it looks like a seriously overkill solution for what I'm trying to do, and the UI looks like a pretty steep learning curve.

Comment: I had exactly the same impression at first. A quick demo from the one who recomended it helped, but just trying it on a few reviews got us hooked in just a few days. That was some 5 years ago or so, they did add lots of features since (but you only use what you need). I never looked back. They have a demo/sandbox area on their site, maybe worth a live try.